# Is there a commercial grade Git server product

Tags: git

Does anyone know of commercial server product for managing Git repos analogous to [FogCreek's Kiln](http://www.fogcreek.com/Kiln/)?

If any, it would be nice to get some rundown of some most notable features it boasts.

It does not have to be necessarily commercial software. Commercially supported would do just as fine, but it has to be installable server software, not hosted service.

Comment: Which features are you looking for specifically? Code review? Web interface? Bug tracking?

Comment: Ideally all three -- With Kiln + FogBugz offering you get all tree.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is also [Atlassian Stash](https://www.atlassian.com/software/stash).

It feastures web based management of public and private repositories, repository cloning/forking, pull requests and source navigation/diff tool.

It also has support for programmable pre- and post receive hooks to your repository and REST API, so you can go crazy customizing your development environment.

There's a healthy [ecosystem of add-ons](https://marketplace.atlassian.com/plugins/app/stash) that can connect your Stash repo to your JIRA, import SVN repositories, add "Sites" for your repository, perform push validation, etc.

Answer (score 5):

[Gitorious](https://Gitorious.Org/gitorious/), the software that runs [Gitorious.Org](https://Gitorious.Org/) is Open Source and can be installed on your own server, and I'm pretty sure if you are willing to pay a decent price, someone would be willing to support it. [Shortcut AS](http://Shortcut.No/), for example, the company which hosts Gitorious.Org and was founded by Gitorious's original author and current lead developer Johan Sørensen, offers commercial support and customized installations both public and private.

And [GitHub](https://GitHub.Com/) has a commercially supported product called [GitHub:FI](http://FI.GitHub.Com/) (Firewall Install).

Comment: Update : Gitorious is no more available now.

Answer (score 3):

GitHub offers [GitHub Enterprise](https://enterprise.github.com/), which allows you to install your own version of GitHub in your company. It has a pretty installer and comes with support, but it comes at a cost.

Answer (score 3):

I don't know what does [Kiln](http://www.fogcreek.com/Kiln/) offer, but there are various tools in various categories:

### Code review tool

Equivalent of Rietveld for Subversion, or Mondrian for Perforce.

- [Gerrit](http://code.google.com/p/gerrit/), used e.g. [in Android development](https://review.source.android.com)

### Git hosting solutions

Like SourceForge, or Google Code, or GitHub.

- [GitHub:FI](http://fi.github.com/) aka Github Firewall Install, standalone version of [GitHub](http://github.com), proprietary (and expensive)
- [Gitorious](http://gitorious.org/gitorious), in Ruby
- [InDefero](http://www.indefero.net/open-source/), in PHP, meant to be equivalent of Google Code

### Git repository management

Includes for example user management, permissions.

- [Gitosis](http://eagain.net/gitweb/?p=gitosis.git), in Python, requires setuptools
  see [Hosting Git repositories, The Easy (and Secure) Way](http://scie.nti.st/2007/11/14/hosting-git-repositories-the-easy-and-secure-way)
- [Gitolite](http://github.com/sitaramc/gitolite), in Perl
  see http://wiki.github.com/sitaramc/gitolite/

---

See also [Interfaces, frontends, and tools](https://git.wiki.kernel.org/index.php/InterfacesFrontendsAndTools) page on git wiki

Comment: Notice that many of these things can be used together.  I use gerrit *extensively*, with cgit for some more detailed views and github for publishing.

Answer (score 1):

For git, what about http://www.clearvision-cm.com ? It looks like you are looking for

Answer (score 0):

I don't know of any Commercial or commercially supported products but will these do?

http://gitorious.org/gitorious

http://www.redmine.org/

I've setup Redmine and Gitolite (for Administration) in a corporate environment and have yet to encounter a driving need for Commercial support as the are both well maintained and have an "Active" community.

Comment: Gitorious was already mentioned in the earlier comments, go give it a vote, if you deem it worth the mention.